# unlike following queries first ajax query returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Have a bit of an issue here. I checked the different answers which seemed related to my problem but cannot seem to get this working.

I've got a page with a link like so :

```
<a href="#" onclick="showData(id)">View</a>
```

And here's the javascript

```
var queryResult;
function getData(id, callbackfn){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"http://url/to/query",
        data:{id: id },
        success: function(data){
        callbackfn(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            return "err";
        }
    });
}

function showData(id){
    getData(id, Callback);
    if(queryResult)
    {
        alert("Yahoooooo !");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Nope !!!");
    }
}

function Callback(data){
    queryResult = data.length;
}
```

When clicked for the first time the link launches the alert box and I get "Nope !!!" but any subsequent click will show a "Yahoooooo !"
If I reload the page then again "Nope !!!" for the first time and then it's fine afterwards. So it seems that queryResult is undefined on the first call but first call only. Any idea ?

Thanx

Comment: By the time you are accessing it, it is not updated..Manipulate it in `callback`

Comment: its because of you function getData is async so before the ajax call is returned i.e a response is received from the server you conditions are evaluted. and thus this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Put your control in `Callback` function

```
function Callback(data){
    queryResult = data.length;
   if(queryResult)
    {
        alert("Yahoooooo !");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("Nope !!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answers. I moved the control statement to the callback and it worked just fine. Not too versed in ajax subtleties but I'm learning.

Comment: You are welcome, you may check other answers for reason why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

You're using .ajax
this method is asyncronous by default.

So you call "getData" then your Data is loaded.
While it is loaded you check if queryResult exists

Then the data has been loaded and your global flag is set

(At the moment you are checking if the previous request was successful)

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call executes **ansynchronously**. Therefore when you call getData(), the method call returns instantly (and the ajax call is executing in another thread). This means the first time you click the link, there won't be anything in `queryresult` because the ajax call hasn't had time to finish before you hit your `if` block, but the subsequent times there (probably) will be, assuming the call has finished before the next time you click the link.

If you have any logic, such as that `if` block which depends on the data being returned from the ajax call, you must include it in (or call it from) your callback function.

So in this case you must move the block:

```
if(queryResult)
{
    alert("Yahoooooo !");
}
else 
{
    alert("Nope !!!");
}
```

from the getData to the Callback function.